# Advanced Configuration Properties/Property pages disappeared in VS2019

Tags: configuration, visual-studio-2019

The advanced project *Configuration Properties* in Visual Studio 2019 (Version 16.11.5) disappeared. I only get the 'non-advanced' version with only a few options.

I mean the properties window where you can set the linker libraries paths etc. I think it is called 'Property Pages'? For example to set these settings: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/working-with-project-properties?view=msvc-160

When choosing 'project'--(right click)-->'properties' I get this instead of the advanced menu:

[image]

Maybe someone has a solution? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it. With C# projects it's not possible to change the linker settings etc. so you get another settings screen.

With a C++ project I get the Property Pages I was looking for.